# Using && in CSS Selector,

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I need to take the CSS selector to use in selenium code the tag is

```
<div id="pbpopup-container" style="border-radius: 10px !important; box-shadow: rgb(170, 170, 170) 1px 1px 5px !important; display: block !important; overflow: hidden !important; position: fixed !important; right: 20px !important; top: 20px !important; visibility: visible; z-index: 2147483647; border: none !important; opacity: 1; bottom: auto !important; height: auto; width: auto;">
```

from this tag I need a CSS selector like '//div[@id='pbpopup-container'] and visibility: visible', can anyone help in this.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have a selenium at hand right now, take this with a grain of salt:

```
//div[@id="pbpopup-container"](contains(@style,'visibility:visible'))]
```

Comment: OP is asking for the CSS not the xpath.

Comment: Well, then your answer would be a better fit.
Perhaps without the `, ` in it (since you only want to have one selector, not two)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the css that you are looking for.

```
div[style*='visibility: visible']#pbpopup-container
```

**Screenshot:**
[image]

Comment: Thank you Supputuri, this works but after clicking that particular div after click I'm changing the visibility to hidden the CSS selector which you provided works even when the visibility is changed to hidden.

Comment: Please check with the updated answer. This will make sure bot the conditions are checked correctly.